# Trouble Parsing a URL

Tags: php, regex

```
$editThisUrl = "<li><a href=\"".$path.$file."\">$file</a></li>";
echo $editThisUrl;
```

So I'm trying to parse "index.php/admin/" out of $editThisUrl above-I can't get the regex right.  I'm working with pretty rigid pathings inside a CMS, any ideas?  thanks for your help

Comment: I don't understand the question. can you give an example.

Comment: $editThisUrl looks like this:
`http://test.example.net/index.php/admin/downloads/HPIM0276%20Alll%20Day%20Long.JPG`

I need it to look like this:
`http://test.example.net/downloads/HPIM0276%20Alll%20Day%20Long.JPG`

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)?

```
$begone_index = str_replace("index.php/admin/","",$editThisURL);
```

Comment: Been attempting with str_replace, and in the case above `echo $begone_index;` gives me the same result as `echo $editThisURL;`